# Error 17807, Severity: 020 - error source identification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, errors

I have setup an alert to notify me on high severity errors. Irregularly, from time to time an error occurs:

*"Error 17807, Severity: 020, Description: Event '31', which was received from the client, is not recognized by SQL Server. Contact the vendor of the client library that is being used to connect to SQL Server, and have the vendor fix the event number in the tabular data stream that is sent."*

The Alert does not give me more information about it. I would like to figure out the source of this error (in principle whatever helps me to identify a user or application or query text or whatever...). I tried to setup an Extended Event session to catch this error and collect an additional data which could help me to identify the error source.

My session is defined as follows:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [ServerErrorMonitor] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported(
    ACTION(package0.callstack,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([severity]=(20)))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'ServerErrorMonitor',max_file_size=(10),max_rollover_files=(2))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_MULTIPLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO
```

It catch the error, but it does not collect any of defined actions and gives me only  basic data as shown on the picture below.

[image: Output from Event Session]

The other catch errors give me additional information as expected, but this one not. There is nothing more also in the error log. I also tried to google the error 17807 but I have not found anything meaningful about it...

Does anyone know some more details about this error (17807)?

Do you have any suggestion how I can identify the source of the error (user or application or query text or whatever useful...)?

The SQL Server version is 2017.